# Add random products to rss every day

Tags: magento-1.9, rss-feed

I've activated rss after I published all my products. Now rss are empty and I think magento will not update them. So my think is, for social sharing purpose, to dynamically update random the rss feed to make them post products on social update. There's a way to add 3 or 4 products each day to the rss? Random or even with a logic.